# Even simplest for loop not working in RStudio

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, while-loop

**None of the previously working for loops in my program are running as expected.** I'm wondering if I've done something to my RStudio env/config to break for loops? ...or perhaps, there's something *extremely* basic that I'm missing here?

Consider a basic for loop example, say

```
for (year in 2010:2015){
print(paste("The year is", year))}
```

For some reason, even this loop returns nothing to my console. Now, consider a basic while loop, say

```
count <- 0
while (count <10) {
  print(count)
  count = count +1}
```

This while loop returns the expected

```
[1] 0
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
```

Comment: You are missing a } in the first loop.

Comment: Thanks! That was a typo in the question, but not the code.

Answer (score 5):

I continued to troubleshoot while typing up this question and actually resolved the issue -- though I'm still not clear on what was causing the problem.

I detached a package I had tried in incorporate into my program

```
detach(package:magicfor)
```

and restarted RStudio. Likely, I just didn't understand what magicfor was trying to do for me even without explicitly calling it in my script.

This was pretty frustrating, and I probably spent 3+ hours troubleshooting complicated loops when it was something else entirely. I hope this documentation is helpful to some of you.

Comment: Just a couple of things: 1. It's always a good idea to restart your R session when running into an error. If you run the bare minimum that leads to the error and it doesn't reproduce it means that you had other things running earlier in your code that caused the error. 2. Don't load packages if you don't intend to use them. 3. R and RStudio are 2 completely different things. The former is actually what is using, the latter makes the former easier to use.

Comment: Solid advice. Thanks!